# Sender ID record when sending email with GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, email, google-apps, sender-id

My GAE app sends email, and I followed [Jeff Atwood's excellent article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html) to improve the likelihood of email delivery.

The first two steps are really easy, but setting up a Sender ID record is more challenging.  The article provides a link to a "Wizard" to help do this, but I don't know the answer to many of the questions in the wizard.

I use Google Apps for email so I'm thinking the Sender ID record should be the same for many other people in my situation (Google Apps and GAE users).

Can anyone point me to a Sender ID record for this?

EDIT:

This [page](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/SPF.html) explains how to set the SPF and SenderID record for Amazon SES, and gives the following TXT record for SPF:

```
v=spf1 include:amazonses.com -all
```

and the following TXT record for SenderID:

```
spf2.0/pra include:amazonses.com -all
```

Leontx's answer appears to give an SPF record and not a SenderID record.

Also, when I look at the headers of the email I send with GAE, there are notes saying that SPF authentication passes even though I haven't added either of the above TXT records to my domain.  There is no info in the headers about SenderID.

I'm still confused about this, but I will now be using Amazon SES to send email.  It is really cheap and it seems that Amazon takes a lot more care than Google to help make sure that email gets delivered.

Comment: did you find a solution? i have exactly the same issue.  thanks.

Comment: Any news about this, I am struggling to get hotmail not marking my emails as junk...

Comment: @payala, For a few reasons, I've switched to Amazon SES for email.  There is some good info here about Sender ID: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sender-id.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's the TXT record I had to create to get SenderID to pass:

```
Host: @
Text value: v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

But I had to get both SenderID and DKIM passing to get mail into Hotmail's inbox.  To get DKIM to pass I had to create a custom domain for our GAE app that matched the domain of the email's From address.  Then I had enable DKIM through that domain's Google Apps account.  Then it finally worked.

Comment: Thanks, looks remarkably simple!  I'll tray it out and mark this answer as correct once I confirm it works for me (or someone else confirms).

Answer (score -1):

GAE mail (I use Python) does not give any feedback when you send mail. To receive feedback you have to use another service /API. I use Amazon SES in my applications.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. What do you mean by "feedback"?